# SL4: How do I change the scale w/o scrolling the canvas?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

We have a large canvas contained in a scrollviewer.  The user can move the canvas by dragging with the mouse, or using the scrollbars.
How can we change the zoom (scale) in the scrollviewer while keeping the current center point?
I think the issue is getting the correct CenterX and CenterY for the ScaleTransform:

```
        var st = MapCanvas.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
        if (null != st)
        {
            st.CenterX = point.X;
            st.CenterY = point.Y;
            st.ScaleX = st.ScaleY = scale;
        }
```

Thanks for any hints...

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked at transforms, but you might want to try setting the RenderTransformOrigin of MapCanvas to `new Point(0.5, 0.5)` (or set it in XAML)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that sounds like it will center the canvas in the scrollviewer, which is _not_ what I want.  If the Canvas is 1000 x 1000, and canvas coord 200, 200 is in the center of the sv, I want to keep canvas coord 200, 200 centered when the scale changes.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Misunderstoond - sorry, I'm not sure how to do what you're seeking.